# Challenges with Key with Gaps?

Tags: postgresql, errors, serialization

I had a mistake with a trigger which resulted in errors in PostgreSQL 9.4.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit. 
Each time during the error, the primary key of SERIAL increased. 
After fixing the bug, the table *measurements* is

```
 measurement_id | measurement_size_in_bytes |             time              
----------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------
              1 |                     77777 | 2015-07-14 18:29:56.858703+03
              2 |                       888 | 2015-07-14 18:29:56.882552+03
              3 |                       888 | 2015-07-14 18:30:15.505957+03
              4 |                       888 | 2015-07-14 18:41:01.878106+03
             39 |                     77777 | 2015-07-15 12:11:21.21391+03
             40 |                     77777 | 2015-07-15 12:11:59.551973+03
             41 |                     77777 | 2015-07-15 12:12:05.48982+03
             42 |                     77777 | 2015-07-15 12:13:02.402053+03
             43 |                     77777 | 2015-07-15 12:13:02.419412+03
             44 |                       888 | 2015-07-15 12:13:02.434728+03
         ...
```

where the amount of error statements has been 35 (= 39-4). 
This jump in IDs may become a challenge later when I want to integrate this table with a partial index where order matters.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE measurements
    (
        measurement_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        measurement_size_in_bytes INTEGER NOT NULL,
        time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        CONSTRAINT no_duplicate_measurements UNIQUE (time)
    );
```

What are the challenges of keys with gaps?

Comment: You simply should not rely on the order of an 'artificial' key (even the sequence can restart, if defined so).  Furthermore, a `serial` is not supposed to be gapless - if you need this, you have to implement it somehow differently.  As possibly the easiest way, you can reset the sequence to `max(measurement_id)` before each insert.  Furthermore, you have a nice timestamp for ordering...

Comment: @dezso Can there be any problems with key with gaps in partial indexes?

Comment: No, but show your (planned) index to get a real answer.  BTW, your unique constraint does not make much sense as `measuerment_id` is already unique.

Comment: max(measurement_id) +1 is a death sentence in case of concurrency. never ever do that ! in case two people do this concurrently it ends up in disaster. first of all i doubt that a normal sequence with no meaning has to be without gaps. in case you really need one: create a second table with just one entry, which serves as serialization tool

Comment: @Hans-JürgenSchönig as the column is the PK, the problems would be prevented by the constraint.  One has to handle the resulting error for sure :)  Other than that, you are right - some sort of serialization (be it explicit locking and/or lookups to another table or else) is needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you see is completely [normal and expected](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).

> **Note**: Because smallserial, serial and bigserial are implemented using sequences, there may be "holes" or gaps in the sequence of
>   values which appears in the column, even if no rows are ever deleted.
>   A value allocated from the sequence is still "used up" even if a row
>   containing that value is never successfully inserted into the table
>   column. This may happen, for example, if the inserting transaction
>   rolls back.

Unless you really need a gapless series of values, you don't have to worry about it.  This is how most (well over 99%, I guess) database tables work.

If you need it, be careful if you have concurrent inserts on the table - you will need some locking to exclude the possibility of choosing the same value by two or more sessions running in parallel.